# Why hasOwnProperty method doesn't eliminate {} type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a complex type **ReactNode** from **@types/react 16.9.17** version and **TypeScript v3.7.4** version.

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';
```

and I want to reduce this type to type, which has property **children**.

I'm trying to achieve this using implicit type-guards:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react';

function func(x: ReactNode) {
  if (typeof x === 'object' && x !== null && x.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
    x.children
  }
}
```

but I see error **Property 'children' does not exist on type '{}'**.

**Questions:**

1. **Why I see this error** (why typescript doesn't eliminate empty `{}` type after `hasOwnProperty()` check)?
2. How in general eliminate `{}` type from `{} | Type` types?
3. How to reduce **ReactNode** type to type, having **children** property?

[image]

Comment: isn't `x` supposed to be of type `Component` or `React.Component` ?

Answer (score 1):

`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` doesn't narrow your type with the control flow (signature below):

```
hasOwnProperty(v: PropertyKey): boolean;
```

In order to make it a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types), you could add a global signature for `hasOwnProperty` ([related](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20363) [issues](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18282)):

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    hasOwnProperty<K extends string>(v: K): this is Record<K, any>;
  }
}
```

Then `x` will be narrowed correctly (in this case to `React.ReactPortal`):

```
function func(x: ReactNode) {
    if (typeof x === 'object' && x !== null && x.hasOwnProperty("children")) {
        x.children // x: React.ReactPortal
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJknAL5wBmUEIcA5FATIwNwCwAUDz2WgA2KFnADmgiACMUg3DziK4wAHYwkUaunIB5KQCskGedyVm4ACxQBnHQHcVABTpgNMAJ4AeANJwkAD3UVEms4axgoVTEAPgAKADcALjhvAEpkmAtgUOz8NGgSH2wUFXdorlMlCh5q3m5qAFcVDGAIFRomtFj-ZOR0GGIyVJMzYGo4WI9XCHH-OABeRaZpQwxGOAAyDbg5gEIllQbBOS2dgDorWwdnCFdYd1iAIjQswRIWFUfU4ZwFc0V-GcXsA3h84AB6cE7XqsM59DCOaAwWR-RS1ChAA)